# How to implement "import" syntax in ES6 in ES5

Tags: ecmascript-6

All:

I have never learnt ES6 before, but when I tried React Router, the guide is almost written in ES6, and there is a part using 'import A from b', after looking it up, it turns out that that is ES6 syntax, I wonder how can I implement this with ES5? Is this just a simplely using:

```
var A = require("b");
```

Thanks

Comment: Just run the ES6 code through a transpiler and have a look. If you transpile to CommonJs modules, yes, that's how it would look like.

Comment: @Bergi  thanks, but could you tell me how to transpile that code? I try to use reactify, but it said:  Parse Error Illegal import declaration

Comment: Try babel. Reactify doesn't seem to support ES6 modules.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks I will find some tutorial about that.

Comment: Plus `reactify` is deprecated :)

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks for this info.

Comment: Are you asking how to consume React Router in ES5 CommonJS, or what are the closest ES5 equivalents to ES6 module syntax in general?

Answer (score 1):

I find that babel works best for transpiling the code. It is the same as a require but the new import and export is more flexible. For easy use with react I would definitely look into jspm http://jspm.io/docs/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Like others have been saying, you're going to want to use a transpiler for your code - and babel is what you're looking for.

Depending on the size of your project, implementing something like webpack will be very useful for compiling your project.

There's some great tutorials on building out an application with react, webpack, and babel. There's some great boilerplates out there too.

This medium post does an amazing job going through setting up an isomorphic/universal application with redux! https://medium.com/front-end-developers/handcrafting-an-isomorphic-redux-application-with-love-40ada4468af4#.x6h3b717u

---

now regarding your question - Yes. import's are just a simpler, nicer way of using require :)